# Word2Vec from scratch with Python

Tags: python, word2vec, loss-function, word-embedding

I'm studying about Word2Vec and trying to build from scratch with Python. I found some good explanation about word2vec model and its implementation.

[word2vec-from-scratch-with-python-and-numpy](https://nathanrooy.github.io/posts/2018-03-22/word2vec-from-scratch-with-python-and-numpy/)

[github](https://github.com/nathanrooy/word2vec-from-scratch-with-python/blob/master/word2vec.py)

As using the same code for practice, only changed the training data to '[alice_in_wonderland.txt](https://gist.github.com/phillipj/4944029)' used only Chapter 1 part.

But as I train the model, the Loss keeps remaining so big, such as converging into 30,000. I have no idea what's going wrong because I think that all forward, backprop, loss function are properly defined. Please help me.

I tried to change 'n: dimension of word embeddings', 'window size', 'learning rate', but nothing did work as I expected the loss to be less than 1.

Below is my code with jupyter notebook.

```
#--- IMPORT DEPENDENCIES ------------------------------------------------------+

import numpy as np
import re
from collections import defaultdict

#---Import for graph-----------------------------------------------------------+

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import clear_output

#--- CONSTANTS ----------------------------------------------------------------+


class word2vec():
    def __init__ (self):
        self.n = settings['n']
        self.eta = settings['learning_rate']
        self.epochs = settings['epochs']
        self.window = settings['window_size']
        self.losses = [] # added
        pass
    
    
    # GENERATE TRAINING DATA
    def generate_training_data(self, settings, corpus):

        # GENERATE WORD COUNTS
        word_counts = defaultdict(int)
        for row in corpus:
            for word in row:
                word_counts[word] += 1

        self.v_count = len(word_counts.keys())

        # GENERATE LOOKUP DICTIONARIES
        self.words_list = sorted(list(word_counts.keys()),reverse=False)
        self.word_index = dict((word, i) for i, word in enumerate(self.words_list))
        self.index_word = dict((i, word) for i, word in enumerate(self.words_list))

        training_data = []
        # CYCLE THROUGH EACH SENTENCE IN CORPUS
        for sentence in corpus:
            sent_len = len(sentence)

            # CYCLE THROUGH EACH WORD IN SENTENCE
            for i, word in enumerate(sentence):
                
                #w_target  = sentence[i]
                w_target = self.word2onehot(sentence[i])

                # CYCLE THROUGH CONTEXT WINDOW
                w_context = []
                for j in range(i-self.window, i+self.window+1):
                    if j!=i and j<=sent_len-1 and j>=0:
                        w_context.append(self.word2onehot(sentence[j]))
                training_data.append([w_target, w_context])
        return np.array(training_data)


    # SOFTMAX ACTIVATION FUNCTION
    def softmax(self, x):
        e_x = np.exp(x - np.max(x))
        return e_x / e_x.sum(axis=0)


    # CONVERT WORD TO ONE HOT ENCODING
    def word2onehot(self, word):
        word_vec = [0 for i in range(0, self.v_count)]
        word_index = self.word_index[word]
        word_vec[word_index] = 1
        return word_vec


    # FORWARD PASS
    def forward_pass(self, x):
        h = np.dot(self.w1.T, x)
        u = np.dot(self.w2.T, h)
        y_c = self.softmax(u)
        return y_c, h, u
                

    # BACKPROPAGATION
    def backprop(self, e, h, x):
        dl_dw2 = np.outer(h, e)  
        dl_dw1 = np.outer(x, np.dot(self.w2, e.T))

        # UPDATE WEIGHTS
        self.w1 = self.w1 - (self.eta * dl_dw1)
        self.w2 = self.w2 - (self.eta * dl_dw2)
        pass


    # TRAIN W2V model
    def train(self, training_data):
        # INITIALIZE WEIGHT MATRICES
        self.w1 = np.random.uniform(-0.8, 0.8, (self.v_count, self.n))     # embedding matrix
        self.w2 = np.random.uniform(-0.8, 0.8, (self.n, self.v_count))     # context matrix
        
        # CYCLE THROUGH EACH EPOCH
        for i in range(0, self.epochs):

            self.loss = 0

            # CYCLE THROUGH EACH TRAINING SAMPLE
            for w_t, w_c in training_data:

                # FORWARD PASS
                y_pred, h, u = self.forward_pass(w_t)
                
                # CALCULATE ERROR
                EI = np.sum([np.subtract(y_pred, word) for word in w_c], axis=0)

                # BACKPROPAGATION
                self.backprop(EI, h, w_t)

                # CALCULATE LOSS
                self.loss += -np.sum([u[word.index(1)] for word in w_c]) + len(w_c) * np.log(np.sum(np.exp(u)))
                #self.loss += -2*np.log(len(w_c)) -np.sum([u[word.index(1)] for word in w_c]) + (len(w_c) * np.log(np.sum(np.exp(u))))
                
            print('EPOCH:',i, 'LOSS:', self.loss)
            self.losses.append(self.loss)
            self.plot_losses()
        pass
    
    # Add this method
    def plot_losses(self):
        clear_output(wait=True)
        plt.plot(self.losses)
        plt.ylabel('Loss')
        plt.xlabel('Epoch')
        plt.show()
    
    # input a word, returns a vector (if available)
    def word_vec(self, word):
        w_index = self.word_index[word]
        v_w = self.w1[w_index]
        return v_w


    # input a vector, returns nearest word(s)
    def vec_sim(self, vec, top_n):

        # CYCLE THROUGH VOCAB
        word_sim = {}
        for i in range(self.v_count):
            v_w2 = self.w1[i]
            theta_num = np.dot(vec, v_w2)
            theta_den = np.linalg.norm(vec) * np.linalg.norm(v_w2)
            theta = theta_num / theta_den

            word = self.index_word[i]
            word_sim[word] = theta

        words_sorted = sorted(word_sim.items(), key=lambda word_sim: word_sim[1], reverse=True)

        for word, sim in words_sorted[:top_n]:
            print(word, sim)
            
        pass

    # input word, returns top [n] most similar words
    def word_sim(self, word, top_n):
        
        w1_index = self.word_index[word]
        v_w1 = self.w1[w1_index]

        # CYCLE THROUGH VOCAB
        word_sim = {}
        for i in range(self.v_count):
            v_w2 = self.w1[i]
            theta_num = np.dot(v_w1, v_w2)
            theta_den = np.linalg.norm(v_w1) * np.linalg.norm(v_w2)
            theta = theta_num / theta_den

            word = self.index_word[i]
            word_sim[word] = theta

        words_sorted = sorted(word_sim.items(), key=lambda word_sim: word_sim[1], reverse=True)

        for word, sim in words_sorted[:top_n]:
            print(word, sim)
            
        pass

import string
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')

# 파일 읽기 및 전처리 함수
def preprocess(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        text = f.read().lower()
        text = text.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))  # punctuation 제거
        tokenized_text = nltk.word_tokenize(text)  # tokenizing
        return tokenized_text

# 학습시키기 위한 텍스트 파일 불러오기
file_name = 'alice_wonderland_small.txt'  # 이곳에 사용하려는 텍스트 파일 이름 입력
corpus = [preprocess(file_name)]  # 전처리 후 corpus로 사용

settings = {
    'n': 100,  # dimension of word embeddings
    'window_size': 2,  # context window +/- center word
    'min_count': 5,  # minimum word count
    'epochs': 100,  # number of training epochs
    'neg_samp': 5,  # number of negative words to use during training
    'learning_rate': 0.01  # learning rate
}
np.random.seed(0)

w2v = word2vec()

# generate training data
training_data = w2v.generate_training_data(settings, corpus)

# train word2vec model
w2v.train(training_data)
```

Comment: What makes you expect your loss values are bad? Do the word-vectors seem to work for usual word-vector purposes? (Are related words 'near' each other?)

Comment: @gojomo After I finished training the model, I checked top 10 words with the function word_sim. The result seems strange, not expected. I'm curious about how to properly construct training data, even though there's a function called 'generate_training_data' inside word2vec class. My alice_wonderland.txt have several sentences split with \n.

Comment: What makes you expect your loss-values are bad? Did you see some other online implementation of word2vec-from-scratch that shows lower per-eopch losse values, on the same data/parameters? Word2vec models can be good for actual purposes with high epoch loss, and bad for actual purposes with low loss - the loss is *only* the internal optimization target – when it can't be improved any more,  the model is "as good as possible given the training data & parameters". But the only real test of success is if the end word-vectors work for usual purposes.

Comment: You don't say what word you used as the origin for your `word_sim()` test, but a good model trained on suitable natural language data **should** show the most-similar words as fitting usual human ideas of word-similarity. Without seeing how they're 'strange' it's hard to guess what would be going wrong, but note that a mere single book chapter may not be enough text to train-up 100-dimensional vectors on the words of that chapter. This algorithm relies on *many, many* varied usage-contexts to create its desirable effects. So tests of effectiveness should use far more training data.

Comment: Finally, I'd point out that your source – https://nathanrooy.github.io/posts/2018-03-22/word2vec-from-scratch-with-python-and-numpy/  – never actually demonstrates their code *working* to create verifiably-useful word-vectors. So if feeding that code adequate training data still gives bad word-vector similarities, it might just be broken code! You could inform its author, but mainly then choose another model to learn from.

Comment: @gojomo Thank you so much for your detailed reply. I never tried this kind of small project but from this trial and your comments, I've learned a lot. I didn't check the code again by the weekend, so after re-checking the code with my data I'll let you know about my results. Thank you again. :)

Comment: @gojomo I finished training with 'Alice_in_wonderland.txt' data(with full content, not only one chapter), with 
    settings = {
    'n': 100,  # dimension of word embeddings
    'window_size': 2,  # context window +/- center word
    'min_count': 5,  # minimum word count
    'epochs': 100,  # number of training epochs
    'neg_samp': 5,  # number of negative words to use during training
    'learning_rate': 0.01  # learning rate
}
and using word_sim function to find words similar with 'alice', top 10 words, the results are as below.
alice 1.0
hastily 0.3890125137
mouse 0.385968286

Comment: @gojomo And now I'm curious about how to figure out whether my model is properly trained with my data. Also if I want to use my trained model again in other environments, should I save trained parameters such as 'w1', 'w2', 'word_index', 'index_word' in this case?

Comment: A single book's text still isn't really typical, or likely enough, to get very-good word-vectors, especially at 100 dimensions. From online sources, it seems the book is only about 25k words total, and from an online frequency-demo (https://codepen.io/Tumwine/pen/ExxJXEx) which I adapted to show top-1000 words, it looks like there's only 687 words with at least 5 occurrences. A 100-d model of a mere 687 words won't have gone through the tug-of-war, *forcing* the model to slot related words near each other, that's central to the word2vec algorithm's benefits.

Comment: And, probing by the name of a unique character (`'alice'`) will be less-informative about quality than trying some common words. (Names are to some extent arbitrary, with only the meanings given by local context/reassigned-relations, as opposed to words with enduring meanings & stable 'neighbors' in meaning-space.) So you should be sanity-checking with well-understood common words – and if your results remain underwhelming, with your current setup it's hard to guess whether that's due to insufficient data or some other bug.

Comment: More typical training runs would use **at least* 10s-of-millions of words, or even billions (like full text of Wikipedia). The practical test of whether your implementation is doing well would be to compare the sensibility & utility of its results, given adequate training material, against a widely-used/well-established word2vec implementation. With roughly same params & training data, each run's vectors may be in varied places, *but* the utility of word-to-word comparisons/distances should be roughly similar. (Words should have sensible, & mostly-the-same, neighbors across implementations.)

Comment: Yes, if you want to be able to reuse your vectors or model later, you'll want to be able to save & reload it. Python's `pickle()` facility for saving/reloading objects may be enough for your purposes. But beyond learning the algorithm, for use in other projects, it'd be safer to use some popular off-the-shelf implementation: it will have features & optimizations not in your code, & is less likely to have new/not-yet-noticed bugs.

Comment: @gojomo Thank you so much again for your kind reply. I'll read all your feedback and let you know again!